# How to reuse an Observer in case of failure?

Tags: android, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-android, rx-java2

I have an Activity which loads data from the network and has a "retry" button if the request fails which just re-makes the same network call. This is the simplified code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private DisposableObserver<Data> disposableObserver;

    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    loadData();
                }
            });
    }

        private void loadData() {

            disposableObserver = control.fetchFromNetwork().subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<Data>() {

                @Override
                public void onNext(Data data) {
                    updateUI(data);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
                    showError();
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            if (disposableObserver != null && !disposableObserver.isDisposed()) {
                disposableObserver.dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

For what it's worth, this is the method that creates the `Observer`:

```
public Observable<Data> fetchFromNetwork() {
    return getService().fetchdata()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnError(new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(Throwable t) throws Exception {
                    exceptionHandler.handle(t);
                }
            });
}
```

I'm using a `DisposableObserver` so it can be properly disposed of in the Activity's `onDestroy()` method.

In this code, every button click will create a new `Observable` and `subscribe` to it, creating a leak since only the last one is disposed of in the `onDestroy()` method. My question is: is there a way to retry/replay this same observer which already exists without having to create a new one every time? Or, is there a better approach to this scenario?

Comment: `is there a way to retry/replay this same observer`: if it has already been completed/failed, then a new one should be created. If it is still being exectued - you can make use of `share()` operator in order to subscribe to the same observable from multiple subscriptions.

Answer (score 1):

So you need to create a new`Observable` every time, to avoid the leaking issue you can create a `CompositeDisposable` and use the `add` method that receives the Disposable created after calling the `.subscribe()`. Then on `onDestroy()` simply call `clear()` and it will dispose every not disposed `Disposable`.